# Keyboard Shortcut to Publish Post on the Mac

Tags: wysiwyg

What's the keyboard shortcut to update posts? I've read that it's Alt + Shift + p, but that doesn't work on my Mac, nor does Ctrl + Shift + p.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need the <kbd>Apple/Cmd</kbd> key instead of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key as the <kbd>Ctrl/Strg</kbd> is not the replacement for the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

So it should be <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

*Note: I'm no Mac user, so you'll to search the proper replacement in case yourself.*

Comment: Very good to know. I don't know how many time I hit cmd s out of habit.